# No USB-autoboot, although manual works

Tags: boot, usb

I have a Linux (Mint) installed on a USB pen drive (made from VirtualBox by installing to this USB device - so it's not a LiveUSB installation medium).

I can boot this stick, when I select it manually as the starting device. But it won't boot automatically, even though it's set to do so in the BIOS:

[image]

The problem doesn't occur on all my machines: I have about 50 HP 250 G6 Laptops at my disposal - half of them do auto-boot into linux, the other half does boot windows...
I also have several (cloned) USB-drives - the problem seems to be independent from the actual drive in use :-(.

Anybody any idea, what's going on here?

I just discovered, that a normal live-USB does boot, indeed, automatically. What may there be the configuration issue?

Thanks a lot in advance for any ideas,
pheidrias

Comment: this doesn't look to be an ubuntu issue, but a BIOS issue. Please refer to your motherboard/laptop manual. O jea, and Linux mint is AFAIK off topic on askubuntu

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the comments.

As my problem concerns the very basics of the underlying system, I thought it would fit here (as this problem seems quite irrelevant to the Desktop or whatsoever in use)...

And the manual of the motherboard surely won't state: our BIOS has problems with USB-sticks on some of our machines, although they are the same model etc. ...

That's why I'm asking - maybe somebody knows how to prepare (any!) linux stick to make it more reliable in booting...